# Vue and TypeScript not reactive for string array values

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a simple UI where the user can define 1:n mappings for form fields. The model is very simple:

```
export interface IMapping {
    pdfName: string;
    fieldNames: string[];
}
```

The problem is, changes to `fieldNames` is not reactive. Here is my code for the form which should work for editing and adding a new mapping.

**Template:**

```
<form @submit.prevent>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="pdfName">PDF Field Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="pdfName" id="pdfName" required
            v-model="data.pdfName"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <fieldset v-for="(fieldName, index) in data.fieldNames" :key="index">
            <legend>Form Field</legend>
            <div class="field">
                <label :for="'name_' + index">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" :id="'name_' + index" required
                    v-model="fieldName"/>
            </div>
            <button @click="removeField(index)" class="removeField"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
        </fieldset>
        <button @click="addField"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonrow">
        <button @click="save">Save</button>
        <button @click="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript component**

```
import { Component, Emit, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

import { IMapping } from '@/models/IMapping';

@Component
export default class MappingForm extends Vue {

    public data: IMapping | null = null;

    @Prop({type: Object})
    private mapping!: IMapping;

    public created() {
        this.data = {...this.mapping};
    }

    public addField() {
        this.data!.fieldNames.push('');
    }

    public removeField(index: number) {
        this.data!.fieldNames.splice(index, 1);
    }

    @Emit('mapping-changed')
    public save() {
        if (this.mapping === null) {
            return this.data;
        } else {
            Object.assign(this.mapping, this.data);
            return this.mapping;
        }
    }

    @Emit('mapping-unchanged')
    public cancel() {}

}
```

I copy the prop to a local variable so I can easily undo any changes and only apply them with save. It reacts to the push and the splice but the string values are not updated.
I tried to use `@Watch` but I am not sure on how to use it in this case as I don't have a method to listen to, but only the user input on my 
`<input type="text" name="name" :id="'name_' + index" required v-model="fieldName"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" :id="'name_' + index" required v-model="data.fieldNames[index]"/>
```

Maybe the problem is that v-for is not passing the reference because it's a primitive type.

Comment: Haven't thought of that. Was thinking it might be the primitive type that causes the issue and considered having a dummy object with just a value prop instead. But this seems to work as expected.